# Loop through global macros

Tags: stata

I'm new to Stata and I have a set of variables as in :

```
global var1  " age sex"

global var2  "area"

global var3  "race"
```

And I want to loop through the 3 variables and apply a function such as:

```
foreach a in $var1 $var2  $var3   { some function given `a'}
```

but the problem is that this function is applied one by one through the content of the varlist and a for `var1` takes first value `age` and then `sex` when I want it to take `age sex`. Do you have any insights for this issue?

Comment: Note that the left brace `{` cannot be followed by other code on the same line. It's clear to me as to you that are giving pseudocode but anyone new to Stata should be clear on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various work-arounds for this. An easy one can be seen in

```
global var1 "age sex"

global var2 "area"

global var3 "race"

forval j = 1/3 { 
    di "${var`j'}"
}
```

Your question raises various small side-issues:

1. Although similar items would be called *variables* in other languages, global macros are not regarded as variables in Stata, as variables are (only) variables, meaning columns in the dataset.
2. Similarly, what you call functions are more likely to be commands in Stata. Commands and functions are not synonymous in Stata.
3. It is much better to use local macros for the purpose you show. That is general good programming style.

Comment: Hi @NickCox , thank you for the insight. Funny I just found your answer in [link](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1297057-how-to-code-so-that-consecutive-globals-are-called-within-a-foreach-loop) to solve the issue too. If you could elaborate on how to do the same with local macros, I would appreciate but even so THANK YOU!

Comment: Good. If you read the entire Statalist thread you will see that your question on local macros is answered as well.